# How to pass selected table items to function in Angular/PrimeNg

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-table

I have this code snippet of a table with items. After I select my items I want to pass them to my function. It it possible do it in the html?

```html
<p-table [value]=items>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
<tr [pSelectableRow]="item">
    <td>
         <p-tableCheckbox
          [pSelectableRow]="applicationProject"
          [value]="item"
          ></p-tableCheckbox>
   </td>
   <td class="cell-breakWord">
         {{ item.name }}
   </td>
   <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
   ...
</tr>
</p-table>
<p-button (onClick) = "function(selectedItemsIWantToPass)">Button</p-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Row selection demo in PrimeNG table](https://primeng.org/table#single-selection), it provides the `[(selection)]` two-way binding variable to bind the selected item to the variable.

```
<p-table [value]="items" [(selection)]="selectedItems">
  ...
</p-table>

<p-button (onClick)="onClick(selectedItems)">Button</p-button>
```

```
selectedItems: any[] = [];
```

Thus, you can get/access the selected item(s) in the component without the need to pass the value from the view.

Note that in `<p-template>` you are declaring the `item` variable with `let-item`. You should pass the `item` instead of `applicationProject` to the `[pSelectableRow]`.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
  <tr [pSelectableRow]="item">
      <td>
           <p-tableCheckbox
            [pSelectableRow]="item"
            [value]="item"
            ></p-tableCheckbox>
     </td>
     <td class="cell-breakWord">
           {{ item.name }}
     </td>
     <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
     ...
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7t5jnt?file=angular.json)